# Clipping regions in python

Tags: python, scripting

I have a complicated model. To facilitate easy access to interiors, i wanted to create 4 buttons that can clip the model from different perspective. As a first step, i was trying to clip regions in the viewport using bpy. But this does not seem to do anything. Can someone please help?

```
import bpy

for a in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if a.type == "VIEW_3D":
        for r in a.regions:
            if r.type == "WINDOW":
                regionwin = r.data

                regionwin.use_clip_planes = True
                regionwin.clip_planes=[
                (-0.2, 0.3, 0.9, 2.7),
                (-0.8, -0.4, 0.0, 3.2),
                (0.1, -0.2, -1.0, 1.4),
                (0.7, 0.6, 0.0, 3.8),
                (0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.6),
                (0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.6),
                ]
                regionwin.update()
                r.tag_redraw()
        a.tag_redraw()
```

Comment: I tried doing it some time ago and it was very inconsistent. I concluded that it's only possible to use this feature reliably with the operator, which makes it next to impossible to do it by code. Happy to be proven wrong though :)

Comment: Yes, i too started getting the same feeling on the reliability. I am now trying with "bpy.ops.view3d.clip_border"

Comment: @Gorgious, i got it to work using a workaround. I am still figuring out what needs to go into clip_planes. I will post the answer here, hoping that someone does not close this question before that :)

Comment: Please do, I'd be interested in seeing that workaround :)

Comment: @Gorgious, if you call clip_border and then set the clip_planes, it is more or less stable. I know, it looks a bit hacky solution. Anyways, with that i created a free addon https://github.com/rmk-repos/clipper which is in its final testing

Comment: Hello, did you ever happen to make it work ? :)